# Excel: YES/NO output

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't have my head wrapped around the following problem.
In excel I need to figure out if an order is ready for shipping.

This is easier to explain with the following picture:

[image: example spreadsheet]

In column A I have different order numbers. Each order can contain more than 1 line.
I need to check if the items ( Column B ) are in stock ( Column C ).

If for 1 order, that can consist out of more lines ( rows ), has not all items in stock it has to output a `YES` or `NO` in Column D for each item in that specific order.

I manually filled in column D for demo purposes. That's what it should look like.

There is a way using pivot tables but I prefer a more elegant way.

I hope to receive some input

Many thanks in advance!

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 you will want the below formula, and drag down.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,C:C,"yes"),"YES","NO")
```

First it counts the number of times an order number is found, then it finds how many times that same order number has yes in col C, if they match then the outcome is YES if they do not match then the outcome is NO.

Comment: THATS IT!  Thank you very much! I was not able to see that.

Comment: no probs, welcome to SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

In D3 put:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,C:C,"NO"),"NO","YES")
```

And copy down